# ExtJS 4 Application Login & Authentification & Rights

Tags: web-applications, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I'm developing an web application on Ext JS 4 using the new recommended application structure. Therefore I need to implement a authentification & rights system. The idea so far:

1. The server is responsible to ensure the user role and rights.
2. ExtJS frontend has to change according to the permissions and role
3. I use a card layout. The first tab is the login screen, the second the application
4. In my controller I check if the user is logged in. If he has a valid identity I switch to tab 2. If not he is thrown back to tab 1.

My problem now is that I'm unsure about part 2 and part 4? How would you implement these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Once the user is authenticated bring the config options over from the server into a store. For example: `Ext.StoreManager.get('ConfigOptionStore').loadData(/* config data returned from server */);`
- Use the `beforeRender` event to add components to your current view (do this in the controller), like so:

  ```
  init: function() {
      this.control({
          'myPanel': {
              beforerender: function(cmp, eOpts){
              //place the store in a var for easy access
              var myConfigStore = Ext.StoreManager.get('ActiveUserStore').getAt(0);

              //from here you can use add() to add stuff like so:
              if (myConfigStore.get('hasMyButton')) {
                  cmp.add({
                      xtype: 'button',
                      text: 'My Button',
                      action: 'doSomething'
                  });
               }
               //etc...
           }
       });
  }
  ```
- Make sure that at any given time, you update the first record of the store with the current config options (when you `loadData`, load just one record).
- This should get you started in the right direction. Just be sure to create your initial views with the only the most basic components, and then add the custom components based on the user's config.

Comment: Thx, good Idea. I just load a json into a var on application launch before creating the viewport. Considering the mvc structure I build the buttons into the tbar on construction but hide them with the option hidden:true;

Answer (score 1):

You could send unique user "config" file from server depending on user id, so every user has its own config set up the way he wants, also you could use StateManager to save user config after has been changed. This way frontend will change according to the permission and role. For the part 4. i dont see any problem, if you decide to go with card layout...

```
setActiveTab( String/Number/Ext.Component card )
```

**EDIT:**

You can use [getState();](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-getState) from the Ext.AbstractComponent to retrive the "states", and save, so on the next load this state is initialized.This is not depending on Cookie or Local storage, so it will not expire. You can give user a chance to save state after he is finished with customizing Views.

Comment: do you have a tutorial or examples for the StateManager? I'm pretty new to extjs and not getting, how to use it, from the docs.

How would you plugin the login/auth manager? Because the user may leave his pc and the session expires when I have to throw him back to the login screen. Otherwise he will try to save something and won't be allowed to ....

Comment: I found an example, but I guess the statemanager may not be the right thing for me. As I understood the statemanager, it safes the status of my application according to what the user is doing. Thats not exactly that I need. I need to customize the interface. This means. E.g. if the user is allowed to edit, show him the edit buttons inside the grid showing the items and allow him to load and open the edit screen.